# How to pass array of objects to an MVC Controller in Jquery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post an array of objects from js ajax to asp.net mvc controller. But controller parameter is always comes null. Is there a type mismatch or something else?

**Js ajax**

```
    var obj = {};
    var arr = [];

    obj = {
           id: clicked.attr("name"),
           name: clicked.text().trim()
          }

    if (clicked.hasClass("active")) {
        clicked.removeClass("active");
        clickedCount--;

        arr.pop(obj);
    }
    else {
        clicked.addClass("active");
        clickedCount++;

        arr.push(obj);
    }

    $.ajax({
            url: "/Players/Shuffle",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ list: arr }),
            contentType: "json",
            success: function (data) {}
           });
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Shuffle(List<player> list)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Shuffled", new { l = list });
    }
```

**Error:** list in controller is always null.

**UPDATE:**

In addition to the code above, why can't I see a new page with the list that posted to the `Shuffle`? `Shuffled` should be dealing with this.

```
public ActionResult Shuffled(List<Player> list)
{
    ViewData["PlayerList"] = list;
    return View(list);
}
```

**cshtml**

```
@model List<Player>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

 @{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Shuffled";
   }

 <h1 id="test">
    list: @ViewData["PlayerList"]
 </h1>
```

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({ list: arr }),` and add `contentType: 'json'` and change your parameter to `List<T>` where `T` is a model containing properties `id` and `name` (but since your array only contains one object, why post an array?)

Comment: Do I have to pass it with json? Can't I just send it as it is?

Comment: Not unless you use indexed property names -  `data: { [0].id: x, [0].name: y, [1].id: xx, [1].name: yy ..... }`

Comment: In debug, I see the list comes null again but when I run it I see the post values properly in firebug.(Which is the situation I don't understand). Anyways I'm going to update the question now.

Comment: It will not be `null` if you use the code in my initial comment.

Comment: And your making an ajax call, so `return RedirectToAction()` in your controller method is pointless (ajax calls never redirect). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Picking elements from a list, and show them in a new page

Comment: You cant. The whole point of ajax is to **stay on the same page**. Just do a normal submit. And you have now completely changed you question. Please roll back your changes

Comment: So you are suggesting to use url instead of ajax?

Comment: No, A form, and submit your form. Alternatively, have your method return a partial view and update the current page with it.

Comment: Ok then I will try that. I thought you can post your values with ajax and redirect somewhere else in controller.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this, I think it will be work:

**Js ajax**

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Players/Shuffle",
            type: "POST",
            data: {list: JSON.stringify(arr)},
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {}
           });
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Shuffle(string list)
{
    var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var deserializedList = (object[])js.DeserializeObject(list);
    return RedirectToAction("Shuffled", new { l = deserializedList });
}
```